# Spring JPA repository casting error when using JPQL

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I have a PagingAndSorting JPA repository declared.  I am using the @Query annotation.

I am getting an exception when I call the get() method on an Optional object from the findById(id) method of the repository.

The weird thing is it only happens when I use JPQL.

The code works if my query is native:

```
    @Override
public BatchDto findById(String id) {
    Optional<Batch> findResult =  this.batchRepository.findById(id);
    if (!findResult.isPresent()) return null;
    Batch entity = findResult.get();  **<-------- Cast Exception Here**
    BatchDto dto = this.mapper.toDto(entity, BatchDto.class);
    List<BatchTransaction> transactions = entity.getTransactions();
    dto.setTransactionDtos(mapper.toListDto(transactions, TransactionDto.class));
    return dto;
}
```

Inspecting the *findResult* object with a breakpoint - I can see:

```
Optional[net.domain.data.batch@4b8bb6f]
```

when I have nativeQuery = true in the @Query annotation.

```
@Query(value = Sql.FindBatchById, nativeQuery = true)
```

Here is the query being used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(B.batchNumber), COUNT(B.batchNumber) as TransactionCount FROM BATCH B WHERE B.batchReferenceNumber = :id GROUP BY B.batchNumber
```

However if I change it to JPQL and remove the nativeQuery=true attribute - the findResult is

```
Optional[[Ljava.lang.Object;@76e04327].
```

and I get a ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to net.domain.data.batch
```

So bottom line - this works when specify nativeQuery=true and fails when I try to use JPQL.

I would prefer not to specify nativeQuery as we will eventually port this db to Oracle.

Comment: What's the content of the method `this.batchRepository.findById(id);`? You not show the JPQL.

Comment: added the query.

Comment: The query returns two columns, and not an instance of Batch. So you get back a array of objects. That's expected. Why do you think it should return an instance of Batch? It would only do that if your query was `select b from Batch b where ...`.

Comment: So why does casting this using natvieSql work?  It maps the columns from the ResultSet successfully into a Batch object.

Comment: Because SQL doesn't have the notion of an entity, whereas JPQL does. So, when you explitly choose NOT to select an entity using JPQL, but to select two values, it won't select an entity, but return two values.

Comment: So I am not glued to using SQL - the challenge is my SQL needs a distinct operator or a first.  The "batch" object I create is not really a batch table - but rather the transaction table.  What would a JPQL query look like that grabs a distinct or first where id = :id?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the query shown below doesn't return a single `Batch` instance. Since there are `distinct` and `count` aggregate functions, the query will return a `List` of aggregates.
To be able to read that statistics you can add appropriate method into the batchRepository. Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT(B.batchNumber) as dist, COUNT(B.batchNumber) as cnt FROM BATCH B GROUP BY B.batchNumber")
  List<Map<Long, Long>> findStatistics();
```

and then iterate through the list.

**UPD**

If the id parameter exactly guarantee that will return a single record, you can change a return type to a `Map`

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT(B.batchNumber) as dist, COUNT(B.batchNumber) as cnt FROM BATCH B WHERE B.batchReferenceNumber = :id GROUP BY B.batchNumber")
      Map<Long, Long> findStatisticsById(@Param("id") Long id);
```